# Restore possibly bricked WRT54GL (possibly lost IP address)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

Recently I tried (and maybe succeeded) to install the DD-WRT open firmware onto my Linksys WRT54GL.

I downloaded `dd-wrt.v24_micro_olsrd_generic.bin`, placed it in the router's firmware upgrade area, waited 10 minutes, and then restarted the device.

I only have one issue. Right before I installed it I turned off DHCP. Now my computer recognizes a router "dd-wrt", however there is no Internet access and I am unable to access the web based utility.

Using ipconfig, the computer tells me there is no default gateway.

If anyone can help, it would be very much appreciated.

Ask if further information is necessary.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/806656/finding-the-ip-address-of-a-walled-in-router *really* similar - though I went through a *lot* of effort trying to find its IP address - and the process might help. A reflashed DDWRT instance should have default settings so the fact you turned off DHCP shouldn't matter

Comment: @confetti I have tried a 30/30/30 reset multiple times to not avail

Comment: @JourneymanGeek is right, when I flashed my linksys everything went back to pretty much default, with the default IP being `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.1.1`.

Comment: @confetti neither of those work unfortunately, any other ideas?

Comment: @confetti or maybe you can explain how I can go about flashing the router?

Comment: Follow the instructions [here](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54GL) - That's basically what I did for my model and it worked straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a 30/30/30 on the wrt54g series after **any** flash update.

Set a static IP address of 192.168.1.100, 255.255.255.0, default gateway 192.168.1.1

It's probably not "bricked", do the reset then open up a command prompt or terminal window and ping 192.168.1.1 continuously.

The Linux command prompt does it automatically.
Windows it's "ping 192.168.1.1 -t".

While watching the command prompt, hold the reset button for about ten seconds, unplug the power while still holding the reset for about another ten. Release the reset with the power plugged in.

If the bootloader is there, you should see a ping response from the router for roughly 5 seconds. During this 5 second period the router will accept a new firmware image via tftp.

Make sure you are flashing a "**legacy**" or "**VINT**" **mini** image for the initial flash. After the successful flash you can put whatever image you want, STD, mega, VoIP etc.

The timing for the tftp transfer can be a little tricky. You want to have another command window open with the tftp command ready, watch for the first ping response as the bootloader starts.

You may have to try it a couple of times before it actually takes.

Don't forget, after any flash, do a full reset on these routers!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

#### Obtaining Router IP

> Disconnect all other machines from the router and run `arp` in a
>   command window to find out what the IP address is:
>
> ```
> arp -a
> ```
>
> You should receive a response from the router even if it is on a
>   different subnet than your computer. If you've received a response,
>   the output will give you the IP address of the router. Once you have
>   discovered the IP address of the router, change the IP address of your
>   computer to match the subnet of the router.

Source [Obtaining Router IP - DD-WRT Wiki](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Obtaining_Router_IP)

Comment: I have tried this however, my results have not been very clear.                  Interface: 169.254.120.150 --- 0xf
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  175.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static                                                                  ?