# Linksys wrt 54g router with continuous blinking power light

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I updated the firmware on my wrt54g v2 router using dd-wrt v24 micro Olsen wrh 54g in hopes of installing a pvn but couldn't find any place in the setup to do this so I reinstalled the Lynksys firmware something went wrong and now I have a flashing power light and unable to access the web setup to reflash. I can ping the IP address and the dmz light comes on and goes of.I have reset the router several times as per the instructions in here and I tried updating the firmware using tftp2 as described here nothing seems to work. Using tftp2 with a continuous ping I get a message (no response from the server). From what I read here and other places the unit may not be bricked and I should be able to access it. There is just so much information around the net it becomes confusing I was hoping someone might be able to walk me through the steps and where I can clarify some grey areas

Comment: Telnet was enabled by default in these versions. Download putty and try to telnet or ssh to the address that is responding to pings. You can reset the firmware from here. **Don't download images from the router database** download them from the ftp site. The images in the searchable database are Brickville. I would recommend you get a good Image before you proceed further!

Comment: Tried Putty but it will not connect, get an error "timed out

Comment: Did you try both telnet & ssh?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1348311/restore-possibly-bricked-wrt54gl-possibly-lost-ip-address/1348739?r=SearchResults#1348739

Comment: You can use something like tftp32 to push a new image to it, only if it responds to pings in that 5 second period. You also need a static IP set on the computer you are going to flash it from. (192.168.1.10) 255.255.255.0

Comment: Tried both telnet and SSH both will time out and not connect. Tried tftp2 with continues ping and static IP on computer and get an error 'no response from the server' I tried that process at least a dozen times hoping I was within the 5 second time frame